# Batch-Command, Specific Execution-Order and multiple commands

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm trying to execute Multiple Batch-Commands in a specific order. 
After the start of the first 4 commands the end of each command should trigger the start of another.

Example:
Once the command "ExportU1" is finished the command "DeleteU1" should start and after that "ImportU1".

How should I do this and/or is there a more efficent way of calling each command?

My current Code:

```
C:\
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin
start process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ImportDebitor
start process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ExportU1
start process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ExportU2
start process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ExportU3
start process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ImportKF
start process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ImportAPSO
start process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ImportAPGF
start process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" DeleteU1
start process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" DeleteU2
start process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" DeleteU3
start process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ImportU1
start process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ImportU2
start process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ImportU3
stop
```

Answer (score 0):

To wait for a process to finish, use `start /wait`.

As you ask for a more efficient way:

```
set "commands=ImportDebitor ExportU1 ExportU2 ExportU3 ImportKF ImportAPSO ImportAPGF DeleteU1 DeleteU2 DeleteU3 ImportU1 ImportU2 ImportU3"
for  %%a in (%commands%) do start /wait process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" %%a
```

Edit:

```
set "command=process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle""
for %%a in (Delete1, ImportDebitor) do start "Parallel-1" %command% %%a
:wait1
 timeout 1 >nul
 tasklist  /fi "Windowtitle eq Parallel-1" |find "exe" && goto :wait1
start /wait "ImportU1" %command% ImportU1
...
```

This is starting the first two processes parallel, waits for both of them to finish before starting the third one (and waits for it to finish)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer. But I think I didn't explain it very well. My goal was to know when a command was finished, because i wanted to start the "ImportU1"-command only if "DeleteU1" AND "ImportDebitor" were finished. Is there a way to let them listen to the commands throug a loop or something like that?

Comment: give the processes a name (`start "WaitForMeToFinish" process.bat "c:..." DeleteU1") and loop `tasklist /fi "Windowtitle eq WaitForMeToFinish"` until it finds no instances.

Comment: Edited to show you how to do it. Adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any need for START. You only need that if you want to run processes in parallel, or if you want to run the process in a new window.

If you want to run a series of batch processes in sequence, then simply CALL them sequentially.

```
cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin"
call process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ImportDebitor
call process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ExportU1
call process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ExportU2
call process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ExportU3
call process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ImportKF
call process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ImportAPSO
call process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ImportAPGF
call process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" DeleteU1
call process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" DeleteU2
call process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" DeleteU3
call process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ImportU1
call process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ImportU2
call process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ImportU3
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

You may execute a series of processes that depends on each other in a complex way using this method:

```
@echo off

C:\
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin"

rem Set indicator of "ImportDebitor active"
echo X > ID.run
start process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" ImportDebitor ^& del ID.run

start parallel.bat ExportU1 WaitID DeleteU1 ImportU1
start parallel.bat ExportU2 WaitID DeleteU2 ImportU2
start parallel.bat ExportU3 WaitID DeleteU3 ImportU3
```

This is **parallel.bat**:

```
@echo off

:nextArg
if "%1" equ "" goto :EOF

if %1 neq WaitID goto nextProc
:waitID
ping -n 4 localhost > NUL
if exist ID.run goto waitID
shift
goto nextArg

:nextProc
call process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Schnittstelle" %1
shift
goto nextArg
```

In this code, `ImportDebitor` is executed in parallel with `ExportU1` (and `ExportU2` and `ExportU3`). When `ExportU1` ends, it checks that `ExportDebitor` had ended in order to execute `DeleteU1` and, after that, it runs `ImportU1`. The same management is done with "U2" and "U3" corresponding processes.

The rest of processes (ImportKF, ...APSO and ...APGF) may also be introduced in this scheme in a similar way.